# Exclude results from a MySQL UNION query

Tags: sql, mysql, union

What is the proper way to exclude results from a MySQL UNION? I'm looking for the equivalent to:

```
(query1)
UNION
(query2)
UNION
(query3)
EXCEPT
(query4)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT a.* FROM 
(
   SELECT ... FROM table_a
   UNION
   SELECT ... FROM table_b
)a 
WHERE a.x NOT IN (...) 
// or   WHERE NOT EXIST  ....' 
// or   LEFT JOIN table_n ON () WHERE table_n.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use WHERE NOT IN.

Answer (score 1):

### Can the column(s) being compared for exclusion be nullable?

Meaning, can the values be NULL?

If yes - use either `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` - [either of these will perform better than LEFT JOIN/IS NULL, read this for details](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).

If no, use a `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` because it's more efficient - see [this article for details](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is mySQL, however maybe this might work. I use this on SQLServer

```
select * from (

select (query1)
union
select (query2)
) a

where a.column = xyz
```